# Retrain custom language model with the current spacy version (Compatibility issues)

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3

i have installed spacy with two language models: vi_spacy (not from me), which is a custom Vietnamese language model for spacy from [Github here](https://gitlab.com/trungtv/vi_spacy) and the japanese ja_core_news_trf model.
I first installed the ja_core_news_trf  model with the python -m spacy download ja_core_news_trf
command in anaconda command line and it worked without a problem. Then when i installed vi_spacy using  in the command line and trying it out it worked. But when i tried the japanese model didn't work anymore.

Each time i get this error:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'ja_core_news_trf'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

even though when i type pip list command ja_core_news_trf is installed.
After investigating i found out that vi_spacy only works with spacy v3.0.8 but ja_core_news_trf  need spaCy >=3.2.0,<3.3.0 and is incompatible with the current version. After typing python -m spacy info i get this error message:

```
UserWarning: [W095] Model 'ja_core_news_trf' (3.2.0) requires spaCy >=3.2.0,<3.3.0 and is incompatible with the current version (3.0.8). This may lead to unexpected results or runtime errors. To resolve this, download a newer compatible model or retrain your custom model with the current spaCy version. For more details and available updates, run: python -m spacy validate
```

after running python -m spacy validate i get this:

```
   ja_core_news_trf   >=3.2.0,<3.3.0   3.2.0     --> n/a
    vi_core_news_lg    >=3.0.5,<3.1.0   0.0.1     ✔

 The following packages are custom spaCy pipelines or not available for spaCy
v3.0.8:
ja_core_news_trf
```

So my question how can i retrain the custom vietnamese model with the current spaCy version? Of course i tried to contact the developer but he doesn't reply, so i wanted to do it myself it it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nearly all cases spaCy v3 models are forwards-compatible with newer versions of spaCy v3, so download `ja_core_news_trf` and then install the Vietnamese model with `pip install --no-deps` so that `pip` doesn't install an older version of `spacy` as a dependency.

You'll get a warning on load that an older model *might* be incompatible, but test it on your data and as long as the performance is the same as with the older version of spacy, it should be fine to use.

See: https://spacy.io/usage/v3-2#upgrading

You can only retrain the model if you have access to the original training data.